# How to get the current page and page results?

Tags: php, pagination

Here is my pagination code:

```
<?php
  public function getLinks()
  {
    $links = array();

    if (($this->pages) > 1) {
      for ($j = 1; $j < ($this->pages + 1); $j++) {
        if ($this->page == $j) {
          $links['active' => "$j"];
        } else {
          $links['pages_tag' => "$j"];
        }
      }
      return $links;
    }
  }
```

I want to use array to set current page like this:

```
<?php
$pageResult = $pagination->getLinks();

foreach ($pageResult as $class => $page) {
echo "<a class="$class">$page</a>";
}
```

The `$class` in `foreach` is

```
$links['class'], and $page is $links['class' => '$j']
```

Who know how to make it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since every link must have a class(active or pages_tag), and the page index, the variable $j on this case, maybe the code should something like this:

```
    public function getLinks()
    {
        $links = array();

        for ($j = 1; $j < ($this->pages + 1); $j++) {
            if ($this->page == $j) {
                $links[] = ['class' => 'active', 'page' => "$j"];
            } else {
                $links[] = ['class' => 'pages_tag', 'page' => "$j"];
            }
        }
        return $links;
    }
```

So when you make a foreach you will traverse the array by getting each link at time, once we know that every link has a class and a page index we can echo the links with this code:

```
    $pageResult = $pagination->getLinks();

    foreach ($pageResult as $link) {
        $class = $link['class'];
        $page = $link['page'];
        echo "<a class="$class">$page</a>";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making a mistake: if you want to append in an array all pages, you need to change the `if` validation in your `getLinks` function like this:

```
if ($this->page == $j) {
    $links['active'] = $j;
} else {
    $links['pages_tag'] = $j;
}
```

The above will be a result of something like this:

```
Array(
    'active' => 1,
    'pages_tag' => 2,
    'pages_tag' => 3,
    //. . . some more positions
);
```

Actually the `$links` array is being overwriting by each `if` in your `for` loop, causing that the array has only one element at the end.

Comment: Finally, and according to my answer, your `foreach` code would work well as is.